# Add a reminder from phonegap application

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins, reminders

I am new in phonegap applications. I am working on an phonegap application and i want to add reminders functionality either it a google calendar or anything else. I am searching for this from 6 or 7 days, please let me know how can i do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phonegap local notification - daily](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371391/phonegap-local-notification-daily)

Answer (score 1):

The example shows how to schedule a local notification which will be triggered every day, 60 seconds from now.

```
  var d = new Date();
  d.setHours(14); 

window.plugin.notification.local.add({
    id:      1,
    title:   'Reminder',
    message: 'Dont forget to buy some flowers.',
    repeat:  'daily',
    date:    d
});
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24371488/596952